# JavaScript in Kentico transformation

Tags: javascript, kentico

I created a transformation to view a video file. Here's is my snippets.

```
<div class="gal_albuminfo">
    <h2><%# Eval("Video_Title") %></h2>
    <p>
        <%# Eval( "Video_Details") %>
    </p>
    <p class="created"><span>Album created</span>
        <%# Eval( "VideoDate") %>
    </p>
    <div class="video">

        <script language='javascript'>
            AC_FL_RunContent('codebase', 'http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0', 'width', '400', 'height', '325', 'src', ((!DetectFlashVer(9, 0, 0) && DetectFlashVer(8, 0, 0)) ? 'OSplayer' : 'OSplayer'), 'pluginspage', http: //www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer', 'id', 'flvPlayer', 'allowFullScreen', 'true', 'movie', 
                ((!DetectFlashVer(9, 0, 0) && DetectFlashVer(8, 0, 0)) ?
                    'OSplayer' : 'OSplayer'), 'FlashVars', 'movie= 
         <%#GetFileUrl("VideoFile")%>
          &btncolor=0x333333&accentcolor=0x20b3f7&txtcolor=0xffffff&
          volume=&previewimage=previewimageurl&autoload=on&mute=off');
        </script>

        <noscript>
            <object width='400' height='325' id='flvPlayer'>
                <param name='allowFullScreen' value='true'>
                <param name='movie' value='OSplayer.swf? movie= 
       <%# GetFileUrl("VideoFile")%>
         &btncolor=0x333333&accentcolor=0x20b3f7&txtcolor=0xffffff&
      volume=&previewimage=previewimageurl&autoload=on&mute=off'>
                <embed src='OSplayer.swf?movie=<%# GetFileUrl("VideoFile")%>
        &btncolor=0x333333&accentcolor=0x20b3f7&txtcolor=0xffffff&
      volume=&previewimage=previewimageurl&autoload=on&mute=off' width='400' height='325' allowFullScreen='true' type='application/x-shockwave-flash'>
            </object>

        </noscript>
    </div>
```

Also, I have the 'OSplayer.swf' file in the same page calling the transformation. The challenge is '<%# GetFileUrl("VideoFile")%>' is not getting the video. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I got a broken link for the file OSplayer.swf.What do I do?

Comment: Scrap all the javascript for now. You need to verify that GetFileUrl("VideoFile") is outputting the correct value.

Comment: @Juno, yes I got the correct value of GetFileUrl("VideoFile")

Comment: Could it be that the javascript is called before the GetFileUrl, so the movie path is empty?

Comment: I have resolved it. I removed all this and did the normal mp4 video rendering using video tag. Just that I can't paly flv. :(

Answer (score 0):

Is that/was that your exact transformation, or have you reformatted it for ease of reading?  It looks like it would contain whitespace in the URLs it it is.